# I am using VScode and the images on my localhost website show only after I open the files in vscode. Is there any way to load the images with app.js/-

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yW0O.png) I am using VScode for webdev and the images on my localhost website show only after I open files home.pug and contact.pug in vscode in addition to app.js . Is there any way to load the images with running only app.js?
I have app.js in my main folder(website)
unless i open home.pug and contact.pug the images aren't displayed on my localhost
[inside main folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSt52.png) [inside views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uooAW.png)

I tried changing the port from 80 to 8000 but nothing works.

Comment: "only after I open the relative files in vscode" — I have no idea what this means.

Comment: "the images on my localhost" — With what URLs?

Comment: " I have app.js " — And what does it do when it gets a request for the images? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: By relative files I mean once I open app.js in vscode, it establishes connection on url 127.0.0.1:8000 on the browser but without any image.   Next I have to open home.pug and contact.pug in vscode along with app.js and restart the server to actually make the images visible on 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: (I have added image of contents of app.js now )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so apparently my mistake was that I was opening only the app.js file in vscode and not the entire website folder where I have all the packages and other data. Once I open the main folder (FullstackWebsite) in vs code and run app.js, I can see the images on the localhost:8000 site.